# throwing exception in interval.parse()

Tags: java, jodatime, date-format

I have stored a string in variable called `dataRange` and using `Interval.parse()` method to get an Interval object.

My goal is to check whether that string is in correct format or not and throw `DateFormatExeption` if it is not in the correct format.

```
final Interval validDateRange = Interval.parse(dateRange);
```

Parse function does not seem to throw any exception if it the string in the correct format.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Class `Interval` is not from JDK, is it? Where is it from?

Comment: What is the `Interval` class?

Comment: It looks like you're using JODA time. If this is the case, please add it in your question as additional info.

Answer (score 1):

`Interval.parse()` does not throw a `DateFormatException` if the string provided is invalid.  instead it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.  `DateFormatException` is not an exception class built in to either Java or JodaTime, so you'll need to create it yourself (which is pretty easy)

If you want to throw a `DateFormatException` then can wrap the call in a try block and do this:

```
final Interval validDateRange = null
try{
    validDateRange = Interval.parse(dateRange);
catch(InvalidArgumentException e){
    throw new DateFormatException("date format not valid",e);
}
```

but `InvalidArgumentException` will also be thrown if the string is null, if the dates are formatted correctly but the range is wrong (e.g. the end date is before the start). The exception message will tell you what went wrong, but it may not be correct to throw a `DateFormatException` in all of these cases